# Zooming to k markers around a specific one

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a layer with markers in it, `markerLayer`. I also have one extra marker, `user_marker`. I want the map to fit to show the extra marker and the next k markers around it.

I know there is [leaflet-knn](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn), but it takes GeoJSON, not leaflet layers, and gives back an array of coordinates, which is not quite what is wanted. There is also [leaflet.GeometryUtil](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/), but that only has the option to return all layers within a certain radius, not the k closest.

Is there either a built in solution in leaflet that I overlooked or an easy solution either with leaflet builtins or with an external library to zoom to the k closest markers around a certain marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily need Leaflet plugins. You could simply use the distanceTo method and sort your markers by distance to user_marker. Then you call the fitBounds method. I have created a [working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/vaillant/evhLd0yh/3/).

Below are the crucial steps of the code:

```
var testData = [{lat:37.7859,lon:-122.1362},{lat:37.6921,lon:-122.0312},{lat:37.823,lon:-122.6112},{lat:37.7478,lon:-122.1562},{lat:37.6759,lon:-122.0458},{lat:37.555,lon:-122.050}];

var marker_layer = new L.layerGroup();
var user_marker = L.marker(L.latLng(37.7829, -122.1312)).addTo(map);

//k closest markers
var k = 3;
var dist_markers = [];

$.each(testData, function(index, p) {
     var latlng = L.latLng(p.lat, p.lon)
   var marker = L.marker(latlng);
   marker.addTo(marker_layer);
   dist = L.latLng(37.7829, -122.1312).distanceTo(latlng);
   dist_markers.push([dist,marker]);
});

dist_markers.sort(Comparator);
var close_markers = dist_markers.slice(0,k)
close_markers = close_markers.map(function(d) {return d[1];});
var group = new L.featureGroup(close_markers);

marker_layer.addTo(map);
user_marker.addTo(map);

map.on('click', function() {
         map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
});
```

Comment: That looks a lot like the solution I would have gone for :) I eventuelly went for a solution with `leaflet.GeometryUtil`, with some hackish workaround ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I know there is leaflet-knn, but it takes GeoJSON, not leaflet layers

So? Just put your markers together in a `L.LayerGroup` and use its [`toGeoJSON()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layergroup-togeojson).

With some backreferences, you should be able to fetch markers again from the knn search.

Comment: I actually did that and got back an Array with latitudes and longitudes. At that point I stopped, as I would somehow have needed to convert those back to markers. I instead went for a solution with L.GeometryUtil.

Anyway, the question was if there was an easier solution or a solution that didn't need outside code and some "workaround". It didn't seem there is anything like that out there or on StackOverflow yet, so I asked :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I eventually went for, using [L.GeometryUtil](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/).

```
function fit_around_marker(user_marker, number) {
    if (number >= markerLayer.getLayers().length) {
        map.fitBounds(markerLayer.getBounds());
    } else {
        var p = user_marker.getLatLng();
        var fit_layers = markerLayer.getLayers();
        var fit_array = [];
        var r = 1;
        while (fit_array.length < number) {
            fit_array = L.GeometryUtil.layersWithin(map, fit_layers, p, r++);
        }
        var fit_markers = [user_marker];
        for (index = 0; index < fit_array.length; ++index) {
            fit_markers.push(fit_array[index]["layer"]);
        }
        console.log(fit_markers);
        var fit_layer = L.featureGroup(fit_markers);
        map.fitBounds(fit_layer.getBounds());
    }
}
```

Comment: GeometryUtil.layersWithin is a nice method. I think that the most effective solution depends a lot on the number of markers you have on your layer, the distance between these markers and the value of 'number' in your function. Indeed, in many cases it will be enough to call layersWithin without the radius argument and therefore you will save a while loop. If your markers are very far apart, it seems doubtful to use a while loop with a one-meter unit increase of r each time.

Comment: I agree about the increase, it was the first thing I tested and it was reasonably fast, so I kept it for the time being. Two notes: The increase is in pixels, not in meters. I don't know how that translates to meters. And internally, `layersWithin` does almost the same as your code :) So I would actually suggest that your example is being used.